Mac Studio M1 orange blinking
My Mac Studio is not booting anymore and the led shows a blinking orange sequence. This happened when trying to update to the latest MacOS (Sequoioa).
I have tried to restore it using another Mac but the process is always interrupt at a certain moment (DFU mode).
Thanks for sharing any idea.

Welcome to Ask Different.  Which exact cable are you using and which of the several ports are you using for the restore or revive operation? Not all cables work, only one port works, etc… https://support.apple.com/en-us/108900

Take it to an Apple Store.

The blinking amber LED just means it's in DFU mode. If you're unable to restore in DFU mode with a known-good cable, it has a hardware fault.

Thanks my solution came through this video: https://youtu.be/7FU4O8xl2V0?si=16iwA6eeuwkW1oC1

Would you care to elaborate? Your experience may help others.
